# Printing Log output from /var/log

Tags: unix

In my script ; the following line

```
cat < /var/log/messages*
```

gives this error :

```
./msglog: line 5: /var/log/messages*: ambiguous redirect
```

How can i bypass this error ?

Comment: Are you trying to combine all the files under /var/log/messages using cat?

Comment: Yeh, I was trying to get the combined output of all the message files

Comment: In that case you can probably just do cat /var/log/messages*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work as well

```
tail +1 /var/log/messages*
```

(OR)

Loop through all the files and print them

```
for filename in /var/log/messages*
do
    cat "$filename"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that /var/log/messages* refers to more than one file.
what about this..

```
for i in /var/log/messages*
do
   cat < $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

use `cat /var/log/messages*` or even better something like

`sudo tail -f -n5 $(find /var/log -name \*log)`